# php-fpm: Maintain php_mod logging format

Tags: linux, php-fpm, fastcgi, regex, rsyslog

I recently switched all my lab servers from apache pre_fork/mod_php to apache worker/fcgi/php-fpm, and after getting everything set-up correctly, I noticed one last issue; php-fpm is adding it's own logging "header" to the php error log.

So this (php-fpm adding it's own header):

```
Sep 21 22:01:50 dev-a-1 php-fpm: pool www: 2014-09-21@22:01:50 dev-a-1.sn1.j1n.us DEBUG(7): VB9KzAoAAAQAAFGbEuQAAAAQ: Hobis_Api_Bootstrap initalized (should only happen once)
```

Should look like this (an example of a log entry using mod_php):

```
2014-09-21@22:01:50 dev-a-1.sn1.j1n.us DEBUG(7): VB9KzAoAAAQAAFGbEuQAAAAQ: Hobis_Api_Bootstrap initalized (should only happen once)
```

Because I am logging everything to syslog, and filtering there, I can add a regex like:

```
.*(pool www:)
```

But I am hoping for a more elegant solution. Is there a config option I can set so php-fpm just does a straight pass-thru? I tried setting the `catch_workers_output` to yes, but it didn't help.